# Decoding ARM7 machine language to ARM instruction

Tags: assembly, encoding, arm, decoding, arm7

Trying to decode:

1. `0x15882BCD`
2. `0xC3A01B28`

I keep on getting the `LDMDAHS` instruction, but I know that isn't right.  Could someone help?

Comment: Can you explain the steps you took which led you to that conclusion?

Comment: I get `stcgt 8, cr8, [fp, #-84]!; ldmdacs fp, {r0, r1, r6, r7, sp, pc}` in little endian and `strne r2, [r8, #3021]; movgt r1, #40, 22` in big endian.  I suppose you got the byte order wrong.

Comment: @fuz I was looking at big Endian, I arrived at MOVGT r1 for the 2nd answer but I was unsure how to align it. do you shift the last 12 or last 8?

Also you're right, I did get the byte order wrong..

Comment: @RB I used `objdump` to disassemble the instructions.  I did not attempt to disassemble them myself.

Comment: For the 1st one, it seems the Big Endian format is ORRPL R2, R8, SP, ASR #23 (according to an online converter). http://armconverter.com/hextoarm/

not sure which is right then

Comment: big endian I dont think the instructions change byte order.  if you read them from wherever with a data access then perhaps they are reversed...

Answer (score 1):

```
.inst 0x15882BCD
.inst 0xC3A01B28
.thumb
.inst 0x2BCD
.inst 0x1588
.inst 0x1B28
.inst 0xC3A0

arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   15882bcd    strne   r2, [r8, #3021] ; 0xbcd
   4:   c3a01b28    movgt   r1, #40, 22 ; 0xa000
   8:   2bcd        cmp r3, #205    ; 0xcd
   a:   1588        asrs    r0, r1, #22
   c:   1b28        subs    r0, r5, r4
   e:   c3a0        stmia   r3!, {r5, r7}
```

does this resemble what you were looking for?

byteswapped

```
.inst 0xcd2b8815
.inst 0x281ba0c3
.thumb
.inst 0x8815
.inst 0xcd2b
.inst 0xa0c3
.inst 0x281b


00000000 <.text>:
   0:   cd2b8815    stcgt   8, cr8, [r11, #-84]!    ; 0xffffffac
   4:   281ba0c3    ldmdacs r11, {r0, r1, r6, r7, sp, pc}
   8:   8815        ldrh    r5, [r2, #0]
   a:   cd2b        ldmia   r5, {r0, r1, r3, r5}
   c:   a0c3        add r0, pc, #780    ; (adr r0, 31c <.text+0x31c>)
   e:   281b        cmp r0, #27
```

Note that depending on which version of binutils you might need to mess with .word, .hword, .inst.n, .inst.w  wait that reminds me...

```
.thumb
.syntax unified
.inst.w 0x15882BCD
.inst.w 0xC3A01B28


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   1588        asrs    r0, r1, #22
   2:   2bcd        cmp r3, #205    ; 0xcd
   4:   c3a0        stmia   r3!, {r5, r7}
   6:   1b28        subs    r0, r5, r4
```

Yes, those are not thumb2 instructions (distinct pattern) and they don't look like aarch32, but...

```
so.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   15882bcd    b   620af34 <.text+0x620af34>
   4:   c3a01b28    .inst   0xc3a01b28 ; undefined
```

I don't think its aarch64.